# how can execute nagios commands from command line in linux

Tags: linux, centos, nagios

I am using nagios o centos server and i only want to monitor the localhost only.

I have defined my service like this

```
define service{
 host_name  localhost
 service_description Site1Service
 check_command  check_http-site1
 use   generic-service
 notification_interval 1440
}
```

and

command like this in commands.cfg

```
define command{
 command_name check_http-site1
 command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H site1.dreaddomain.com
}
```

I am getting critical error in there. so i want to check from command line if that service is running or not

Answer (score 8):

You actually have the answer in your config - just execute in shell:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H site1.dreaddomain.com
```

You may add -v for verbose output.

Nagios is only a scheduler and executes commands at specified intervals. Then reports the state based on response.

Comment: On my CentOS 6.5 server the plugins are in `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins`